# Why did part of transaction succeed when another part failed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql

The outer loop reads all the distinct filenames in the import table. Inside the transaction I call a proc that processes the rows of a single file, making various inserts and updates in the system. When it is done, I delete the rows from that file. Then I commit.
Today, I got an error about trying to insert a null value into a primary key. OK, I'll figure out what caused that. But, when I looked at the import table, all the rows for that file were deleted! Why?

```
declare @filename varchar(55);
declare fn cursor for select distinct filename from iox277 order by filename;
begin try
    open fn;
    fetch next from fn into @filename;
    while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
        begin transaction
        exec spIntake277 @filename; -- insert failed here    
        delete from iox277 where filename = @filename; -- delete still happened!!
        commit;
        fetch next from fn into @filename;
    end
end try
begin catch
    rollback;
    close fn;
    deallocate fn;
    select 'ERROR', error_message();
    return;
end catch
```

Here is the body of my main stored procedure that calls an inner sp. The inner has no transactions. The inner made the error of trying to insert the null into a PK.

Comment: In your `catch` you call `rollback` which rolls back everything that has happened so far - including (I am slightly guessing because you don't show us) your original insert into the table.

Comment: Given that your code EATS the error in the catch block, it seems logical to assume the same thing occurs inside your inner SP so that the outer SP does not see the error.

Comment: When the "...insert failed here..." happened, was the transaction marked as "doomed" or was the exception silently swallowed?

Comment: @DaleK I understand why the original insert was rolled back, but the deletions should also have been rolled back.

Comment: @SMor For years I used only the old-style @@error. On this project, I wanted to up my game. Maybe I am not combining transactions and error handling correctly? I assumed any db modification error (handled or not) would be seen by the transaction, but even as I type I am thinking that if the transaction thinks it is handled, then it goes forward with the commit? Maybe I should errors bubble up all the way to the app.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have no idea. My app only received the message about the failed insert.

Comment: @EdLyons I don't understand what you mean by "the deletions should have been rolled back", if the original insert into `iox277` is rolled back then there are no deletions to roll back? The table will be empty. So I don't think its a case of the deletions not being rolled back, I think its a case of the original insert being rolled back leaving the table with nothing in it. If I'm not understanding you correctly then I think your question needs additional clarification, including showing the original insert into `iox277`.

Comment: @DaleK The iox277 table contains the original import (N rows per file) before the sp runs. Rows are read, and then OTHER tables receive inserts and updates. After all the other tables receive their data, then the iox277 is trimmed of the rows created by the original import file.

Comment: Yeah, but does that process happen in one go i.e. in one context with an implicit transation?

Comment: @DaleK Yes. There are no nested transactions. But I think your comments led me to a possible solution. In the nest proc I have try catch blocks set up identical to the parent proc (which is shown above). I return errors via a select statement as if they are going back to the app, which they are not. I think I should use throw in the nested proc so that the error looks like an error to the outer proc which should then trigger the rollback. I'm going to try it next time around. How do I give you credit on a comment?

Comment: _I return errors via a select statement_ THAT is your problem. Don't do it. Rethrow the error.

Comment: You don't need to catch, rollback and rethrow. Just do `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` at the top and the transaction will be rolled back automatically. Quite why you are using a cursor here is a different question

Answer (score 0):

I thank everyone for their comments. They contributed to things I strangely never heard about in my 20 years of off and on SQL programming.

- I am replacing cursors with temp tables:

```
   select (row_number() over(order by <column>))RN, * into #tbl from <table>
```

- I am aligning all my error handling with the principles in this article: https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#error_handler_sp

(Just posting this here hoping it might help someone later)